# Is there a way to drive the Marked Man opponents' version of the Hunter Civilian?

Tags: burnout-paradise

The computer drivers who try to crash the player in Marked Man events seem to drive a black, modified version of the Hunter Civilian (which is the Burning Route version of the Hunter Citizen police car, without a bullbar).

Is there a mod or cheat or any kind of thing that can be done on the PC/Steam version to drive this car?

Comment: If you're asking for a mod, your question is off-topic. If you're not asking for a mod, the [pc] tag is unnecessary.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I'm a bit unhappy with not being able to specify that the solution should work for my game version. If s/o posts an XBOX solution, I sadly can't use it, question not answered for me. In case the solutions are different for different platforms.

Comment: But that's not what platform tags are for. As you should know, "Platform Tags should henceforth only be used for questions specifically about a given platform or console, or a game's interaction with that platform or console". This question is neither of those. Add in the question that you play on PC if you *additionally* want PC-specific answers.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that my assumption that the Marked Man opponents' car was a modified version was mistaken; [it seems to be just the Civilian](http://burnout.wikia.com/wiki/Hunter_Civilian) with a particular paint job (all black) which is selectable by the player.

[Here is a YouTube video which shows the paint settings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HtnY8GAbkg&t=1m33s).